# Is "essere dietro a [infinitive]" widely understood as "star [gerund]"?

Tags: word-usage, idioms, regional, tenses

In Lombardy, I often hear phrases like *sono dietro a cercare qualcosa* to mean *sto cercando qualcosa*.

Is that widely understood, or is there another way to translate the Present Progressive used in English?

To my hears, *sono dietro a [infinitive]* seems a literally translation of an Eastern Lombard phrase, but since there are Italian expressions like *stare dietro a*, *andare dietro a*, *correre dietro a*, I wonder if also *essere dietro a* is understood outside Lombardy.

Comment: Not in Milan: [indree](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=oEkQAAAAYAAJ&printsec=titlepage&dq=Rossi+Secondo+Pavia&lr=&as_brr=1&hl=it&source=gbs_summary_r&redir_esc=y#v=snippet&q=%22indree%22&f=false) is always a pejorative "ves indree a..." means "I'm behind doing..."

Comment: Yes, but in Milan they speak Western Lombard. `:)`

Comment: I am versed in both Milanes (born there) and Mantuan (mother family origin), and I've never heard that form, however my father's side is from further east (triveneto) and I would not be surprised hearing that from him... IMO it seems to be a "triveneto" thing but not, strictly speaking, Lombardy.

Comment: _L'è drè a_ is surely Eastern Lombard. I have heard _è dietro a_ many times in Lombardy, where I live.

Comment: @kiamlaluno in Milan I commonly hear *sön dré* with the meaning *sono dietro a* (I'm doing)

Comment: I would call this a regional feature since it occurs over much of northern Italy, somewhat like the use of passato prossimo for passato remoto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's used also in Veneto (*son drio a fare*/*so drio fare*, depending on the actual location), but it should be marked as dialectal and not standard Italian. I don't think such an idiom would be understood outside Northern Italy.

When I was in elementary school, I frequently heard hypercorrections such as *sono dietro facendo*. Our teachers always frowned upon usage of *sono dietro a fare* (and they were right).

Comment: Definitely not homogeneously understood indeed!

Comment: Triveneto, as said above. The same idiom is used in Trentino : "Som dre a ..."

Comment: Used in Emilia Romagna too. I just realized I use it to convey the idea of a demanding activity that cannot be interrupted right now.

Answer (score 5):

No, "sono dietro a..." it's not a widely understood phrase. The correct Italian form is to use the verb "stare" followed by the gerund.

Furthermore the quite similar phrase "sono indietro a..." means a very different thing: "I'm behind in...", so I would not assume that people understand what you mean.

Comment: A late comment about your _sono indietro a_: It should probably be _sono indietro nel_, even if I normally hear _sono rimasto indietro nel_; alternatively, it could be _sono rimasto indietro con_ (_sono rimasto indietro con i compiti._). In the first case, _nel_ would be followed from the infinite of a verb (_sono rimasto indietro nel fare i compiti_).

Comment: @kiamlaluno indeed, however there are many valid instances of "sono indietro a". For example "sono indietro ad oggi", "sono indietro a livello di...", "sono indietro alla grande" -- besides the invalid, but used, "sono indietro a fare i compiti". If a non native speaker finds "sono indietro a", it *will not* mean "I'm (phyisically) behind something".

Answer (score 2):

I'm from Trentino, Val di Non. In our dialect, called Nones, we also have that expression. It is actually the only way to form the gerund. *E.g. son dria a far bergot - I'm doing something*. Thus, I would assume that this is a characteristic shared with other northern Italian dialects too. In standard Italian, the one of the Accademia della Crusca, it is not accepted. It is a phenomenon of language contact between the two languages, as many northern Italians are bilingual in the two. Because in Italy, speaking differently from the imposed norm is socially looked down upon, I would reccomend you to learn the actual gerund *e.g. sto facendo qualcosa*. But linguistically speaking it is not incorrect if you use it when speaking with people that understand it (basically northern Italians). It is just a phenomenon of language contact, just as the ones that created other accepted features of the vulgar that later became what we know as Italian.

Comment: Welcome/Benvenuto!

Comment: _It is actually the **only** way to form the gerund_, really?

Answer (score 1):

Non so, "*sono dietro a cercare qualcosa*", secondo me, esprime un senso di maggiore disperazione rispetto a "*sto cercando qualcosa [qui dietro]*"; come se nel primo caso la ricerca fosse affannosa, quasi un evento indesiderato.

Invece, "*sto cercando qualcosa*" esprime determinazione, quasi come se il "ricercatore" abbia precisa contezza della finalità e della utilità della sua azione.

Nevertheless, as far as I can tell, "*essere/stare/correre/andare dietro*" are commonly used, and understood, outside Lombardy, also in metaphorical sense.

Comment: "sono dietro a (cosa)" a me non dà molto un senso di disperazione in sé, ma più di un'azione (in genere in risposta ad una situazione imprevista) a cui ci si dedica con grande continuità/intensità/impegno. Del tipo, "sono dietro ad aggiustare un server" non implica che sia disperato, ma che è un'attività importante e di una certa durata in risposta ad un imprevisto, su cui sono concentrato e che non ammette interruzioni.

Comment: @Matteo, si, forse and maybe; però "cercare", differentemente da "aggiustare", è un'attività che molti desiderano non fare. Sicché, generally speaking, è più probabile che "cercare", soprattuto se dietro, crei ansia, diffcoltà, disperazione. Insomma, conosci qualcuno che sia felice di "stare dietro a cercare"? I think not.

Comment: I agree with the general feeling, my objection was mostly in the strength of "disperazione" (desperation), which IMHO is a bit too strong for the normal usage of "essere dietro a fare qualcosa"; one is *disperato* if he has really big problems, but you aren't required to be in tragic conditions to say "sono dietro a (fare qualcosa)". :)

Comment: I think an acceptable translation of the dialectal form *Sono dietro a fare qualcosa* could be *I'm busy doing something*. Desperation is not implied at all, it only expresses dedication.

Answer (score 1):

The *sono dietro a fare..." locution, when not used to express where you're doing something (more explicitly *sono dietro, a fare...*, where the optional comma reveals the difference), is akin to the french form *je suis en train de faire*, meaning *I'm doing that, right now*.

User @GabrielePetronella's comment on another answer talks about *I'm busy doing something* as a possible translation. While I feel that is a really good translation for some uses of the Lombard locution, I feel the Lombard sentence has a wider meaning: *I'm doing something*, for which the correct form in Italian would be *sto facendo*. (Yes, this means the locution you found is just a literal translation.)

Comment: The question is more about _sono dietro a […]_ being widely understood from Italian people.

Answer (score 0):

In Modena we use phrases like *essere dietro a mangiare* and *sono dietro che mangio* as the normal ways of expressing the standard *sto mangiando*. In the local dialect these same phrases represent the only ways of expressing the above notion.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Ma... *Verbare*? *Verbando*? non sono sicuro di aver mai incontrato quest'uso :P

Comment: @DenisNardin Penso che intenda "verbo all'infinito" e "gerundio".

Comment: @kiamlaluno Yes, I understand what he meant. It's just a, uh, creative usage of Italian grammar.

Comment: Yes, it should have been better to use examples with real verbs.